# Get website title without displaying it

Tags: android

I want to get the title of a webpage without actually displaying the website inside my app.

Only want to receive the title. (or header information)

I searched stack, but were not able to find a solution

Comment: is that help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24239268/4108694

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I won't spoon-feed you with code, but you can do it in two ways.

1. Using an HTML parser - Load the website data into the HTML parser and look for the text in `<title>` tag.
2. Manually using `HttpURLConnection`.

a) Connect to the website using `HttpURLConnection`.
b) Read the first few thousand bytes (it will most probably contain the `<title>` tag).
c) Search for the Title using this regex `<title>(.*)<\/title>`. Check the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/gI5vE5/1).

If you want to know how to use regex for title extraction, check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239268/4108694) linked by GeorgeGkas.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I need the html of a page, where I'm logged in with my google account. So same data as chrome